# how to use gmail filter to forward non-maillist emails?

Tags: filter, gmail, forward

I use filters to "skip inbox" and "add lable" to known mail-list senders. So all incoming mail-list emails will be tagged as "Mail-list" and not shown in the inbox. I want to forward the rest emails to another email address. I added a "forward emails sent from * to xxx@xxx.com" filter after the last mail-list filter.

But the "forward..." filter will instead send ALL emails including the mail-lists to xxx@xxx.com. How can I just forward emails without "mail-list" tag.

Answer (score 0):

The only answer I have found to this (still, 2 years after the OP) is to basically set up the forwarding filter with negative keywords or "from" addresses.  In other words if NOT from... then forward.

This may work, but it is completely lame!

What if I have 10 different filters labeling things and archiving them, and then I want ALL the leftover "unfiltered" stuff to be forwarded... I would have to set up a very complex forwarding filter to do that... and even worse, i would have to modify that comp[lex filter every time I change the criteria on one of my other filters.

We really need a way to have filters work in a particular order, prioritization (and a checkbox for each one saying "stop processing additional filters for emails that match this filter" or something).

....OR at LEAST a filter should have an "else" section... IF the email matches the criteria given, do these things..... ELSE do this other set of things.  But even that would not really solve the given problem, or forwarding all emails that do not match any of a list of other filters.)